# Copy a flat numpy array to an given attribute of an np.array of objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can I copy a 1D numpy array to an given attribute of an np.array of objects without using a for loop?
For filling the "percentage" property of all PlotInputGridData objects in objarray with the "dist" array, i use something like this:

```
import numpy as np

class PlotInputGridData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rangemin = 0
        self.rangemax = 0
        self.rangelabel = ''
        self.percentage = 0
        self.number = 0

objarray = np.arange(6, dtype=PlotInputGridData)
for i in range(objarray.size):
    t = PlotInputGridData()
    objarray[i] = t

dist = np.array([52, 26, 12, 6, 3, 1], dtype=np.int)

for i in range(dist.size):
    objarray[i].percentage = dist[i]
```

i need to do

- objarray[0].percentage= dist[0]
- objarray[1].percentage= dist[1]
- ... and so on

is there any way of copying dist[] to objarray[].percentage in a more concise way without the for loop on the last 2 lines?

Comment: If the object array represents tabular data and the class you've defined represents a row, you'd be better off with a Pandas DataFrame. This would let you perform these loop-free operations (and probably everything else you're going to need).

Comment: Thanks YXD, that is a good suggestion. I am aware that Pandas could make this a lot easier but i would like to know if there is a solution using only numpy.

Comment: It is possible by defining some operation to PlotInputGridData like `def __pow__(self, x): self.percentage=x` and later say `objarray**dist`, but I checked: there is no speedup compared to the loop. I think the right way is shown in Warren Weckessers answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that assignment without a for-loop.

You could do it if you used a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) instead of an array of objects.  The class `PlotInputGridData` is just a few fields, so the data it holds is easily represented as a structured data type instead of a Python class.

For example,

```
In [15]: grid_data_type = np.dtype([('rangemin', float),
    ...:                            ('rangemax', float),
    ...:                            ('rangelabel', 'S16'),
    ...:                            ('percentage', float),
    ...:                            ('number', int)])
```

`grid_data_type` is a structured data type with five fields.  (Change the types of the individual fields as needed.)  This data type can be used as the `dtype` of a numpy array:

```
In [16]: a = np.zeros(6, dtype=grid_data_dtype)

In [17]: dist = np.array([52, 26, 12, 6, 3, 1])
```

The following assigns the array `dist` to the `'percentage'` field:

```
In [18]: a['percentage'] = dist
```

Take a look at `a`:

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, b'', 52.0, 0), (0.0, 0.0, b'', 26.0, 0),
       (0.0, 0.0, b'', 12.0, 0), (0.0, 0.0, b'', 6.0, 0),
       (0.0, 0.0, b'', 3.0, 0), (0.0, 0.0, b'', 1.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('rangemin', '<f8'), ('rangemax', '<f8'), ('rangelabel', 'S16'), ('percentage', '<f8'), ('number', '<i8')])

In [20]: a[0]
Out[20]: (0.0, 0.0, b'', 52.0, 0)

In [21]: a['percentage']
Out[21]: array([ 52.,  26.,  12.,   6.,   3.,   1.])
```

Comment: Thanks @warren ! My reputation wont let me up-vote our answer but  that will work as intended and keep the code short and readable. Using a structured array seems the best option as i really don't need to use the class in this particular case.